# Django DRF create new object with primary key "id: null" after axios post method

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, backend, vuejs3

**Summary**

I'm using django and django rest framework as backend and vue3 as frontend to build a website. I also use axios to post data to the backend and it works fine except that every object created in the backend has a primary key "id: null" instead of auto increment id field.

[id: null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDXs3.png)

**Detail**

I know that django will automatically create auto increment primary key for you so I didn't declare this field in my models.py. And it works because I can get the primary key id and display it in the frontend when reading data from the backend.

So I think I can post data without a id field and let django do the work to provide this new instance with an auto incremented id field. However, every time the object is created and every time "id: null".

Here is my serializer for the model:

```
class MaterialSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Material
        fields = "__all__"
```

Here is the object list view code that receives the request:

```
class MaterialList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Material.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MaterialSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
```

Here is my post request from vue3 using axios:

```
    const addNewMaterial = (payload) => {
      axios.post(store.state.backendAPIs.coreAPI, payload.data)
        .then(_ => console.log('...'))
          .catch(err => {
            window.alert('...')
            console.log(err)
      })
}
```

How can I fix this problem or I just need another way instead of letting django generate the primary key for me.

**update**

- Authorization is not a problem. I'm using token authorization and put request works fine and fluently.
- I use sqlite3 in local development and my original database are created from a .csv file. Now when I create new instance using post request from vue3 django always gives a primary id field with value "null". This could be an important thing I forgot to mention.
- I try to carry the id field in the post request and it doesn't work. The object always has "id: null" no matter what id value you post from frontend. (also "id: null" when not carrying id field in post request)
- The objects are created with all fields and valid values except that "id: null" so I can't locate those newly created objects using primary key and it gives me a headache.

And here is my models.py:

```
class Material(models.Model):
    series = CharField(db_column="series ", verbose_name="series ", max_length=100)
    mark = CharField(db_column="mark", verbose_name="mark", max_length=100)
    manufacturer = CharField(db_column="manufacturer", verbose_name="manufacturer",  max_length=50)
    link = CharField(db_column="...", verbose_name="...", max_length=100)
    acronym = CharField(db_column="...", verbose_name="...", max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "test"
```

Comment: What database backend are you using?

Comment: Please share the model code as well

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the Authorization header when making the axios.post call. `IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly` would need an `Authorization` header when making a POST call.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was not returning super() in django model save() method

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.created:
        self.pack_start = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.package = self.employer_status.package.free_job_advertise
    if not self.created:
        self.pack_end = datetime.datetime.now() + 
        datetime.timedelta(days=self.package.validity_period)
    return super(EmployerFreeJobAdvertiseStatus, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```